# Unexpected result when converting datetime(1970,1,1) to seconds

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x, timestamp, posix

In Python 3.5, when I convert POSIX origin `1970-01-01` to timestamp (in seconds) instead of `0` I get the following result:

```
import datetime as dt
t = dt.datetime(1970,1,1)
t.timestamp()
-10800.0
```

Expected `0` is produced by:

```
t = dt.datetime(1970,1,1,3)
t.timestamp()
0.0
```

Both results are quite unexpected to me. What could be a reason for such a behaviour?

Comment: Thanks, would you post it as answer?

Comment: you need UTC timezone, to get zero here: [`t.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian That's cool, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs: *Naive datetime instances are assumed to represent local time*

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html
- timestamp: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp

You get a negative count so I guess you happen to be at UTC-3 (10800 / 60 / 60) (and you get a 0 when adding 3 hours)

Make a timezone aware date and you should be back at 0.

Comment: Indeed. I meant the timezone of your current local time